# Is scaffold no longer valid in the Controller definition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, scaffolding

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController

  scaffold :album

end
```

In a Rails 1.1.6 tutorial I was instructed to put the code "scaffold :album" inside my admin controller. This is a music application containing a model called "Album".

**This generated an error saying that scaffold is not a valid method**.

Is this a deprecated/obsolete syntax in the more recent versions of Rails?

I was expecting this to generate all of the appropriate generic CRUD scaffolding for my Album Model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `scaffold` method was deprecated in Rails 2. See [Why did Ruby on Rails deprecate the scaffold method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526891/why-did-ruby-on-rails-deprecate-the-scaffold-method)

Comment: Ok. Now I feel better. Thought I messed something up. Thanks!